# Hide div based on country of user entering using PHP

Tags: php

I get the ip address of the user who enters this way. No problem with these.

```
function getCountryData() {
    return unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=' . get_ip()));;
}

function getCountry() {
    $languages = [
        'TR' => 'tr_TR',
        'EN' => 'en_US'
    ];
    $response = getCountryData();

    return array_key_exists($response['geoplugin_countryCode'], $languages) ? $languages[$response['geoplugin_countryCode']] : 'en_US';
}
```

This is the normal part on the HTML side.

```
<p class="d-none d-sm-inline-block"><span><a href="tel:000000">000000</a></span></p>
```

I want to hide this part if the user entering TR is entering. I wrote something like this in this, where did I go wrong or how should I do it?

```
<p class="d-none d-sm-inline-block" style="<?php if ($response['geoplugin_countryCode']) {echo 'display: none!important;';} else {echo 'display: inline-block!important;';} ?>"><span><a href="tel:000000">000000</a></span></p>
```

Comment: Would it be better to put the condition outside the `<p>` tags so that the HTML is only included when you want it displayed?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<p class="d-none d-sm-inline-block" style="display: <?= empty ($response['geoplugin_countryCode']) ? 'inline-block' : 'none'?>"><span><a href="tel:000000">000000</a></span></p>
```

here are some explanations:

- condition ? result_if_true : result_if_false is a shorthand for if(){}else{}

  use empty($array['key']) as this will not throw an error if the array key is not set

  !important tag should not be needed and more importantly it is not glued to the condition, it requires a space: display: none !important. You can add it after the php closing tag ?> if you really need it. Just remember to add the space before it: `?> !important`

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare $response['geoplugin_countryCode'] with 'TR' like

```
 ... if ($response['geoplugin_countryCode']==='TR') {echo 'display: none!important;';} else...
```